# Night/Day Cycle Magic

Tags: magic, day-night

How would a world evolve where magic users can either only use magic when the moon is up, or only when the sun is up. How would this effect where magic users live, and how would they interact with the magic users of the opposite order. Where on the planet could they optimize their magic time. How would an eclipse factor into this since both the sun and the moon will be up.

Comment: The North Pole gets a lot of sun for a while and a lot of darkness for long stretches of time but for most of the planet it's generally the same sun up sun down cycle. And as for the other stuff well I guess it depends on how aggressive they are to each other, considering one is more powerful than the other at certain periods of time I guess they would just wait them out until day or night came. An as for an eclipse it could be an big event where they battle or celebrate or just do cool magic together. It's really up to you...

Comment: The Moon and the Sun are both visible very often, and this repeats monthly. An eclipse happens when the Moon passes in front of the Sun; this is indeed rare. On the contrary, simply having the Moon visible on the daytime sky is perfectly ordinary. You may want to look up to the sky from time to time.

Comment: If he lives in an urban area with a lot of smog and assorted light pollution he probably cant see the moon during the day like us country folk can.

Comment: This question is really broad, and can't really be given a full answer without ginning up a lot of setting wholecloth. With magic questions like this it's very useful to be specific about exactly what your magic can and can't do, and with society questions it's useful to characterise the 'base' real world culture you're working from.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: People would be very good at developing calendars. So they would know when the Moon or the Sun or both were in the sky. There would be a major incentive in inventing clocks too.

Comment: I think it is difficult to answer questions about the evolution of magic, especially different types/polarities, with no real indication of how they would differ. I think the question is too broad. Interesting idea though, but it needs some more thought to make it a good question.